# Android: Can't add header to ListView (LinearLayout can't be cast in AbsListView)

Tags: android, listview, android-inflate

I am trying to add a header with a ImageView to my ListView. I put the ImageView in an XML layout and in the Activity I am inflating the layout and add it to the ListView header, but when I run the app it crashes saying **"java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams"**.

I tried changing the LinearLayout to other layouts, but still receiving this error message. Any thoughts?

**list_header_banner.xml code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/publicidadeView"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:clickable="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity inflate code sample**

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvResults);
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.list_header_banner, null);
list.addHeaderView(headerView);

try {
     ImageView publicidadeView = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.publicidadeView);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
}
```

**Activity layout code sample**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lvResults"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    />
```

Comment: I think your header layout inflation code is wrong it should be : LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_header_banner, null);

Comment: Tried that before, and the error changes to "Error inflating class android.widget.AbsListView"

Answer (score 0):

Try to inflate layout using current context (this) :

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.list_header_banner, null);
```

Comment: Tried that before, and the error changes to "Error inflating class android.widget.AbsListView"

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using this snippet and it works for me.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout headerLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header_banner, null);
listView.addHeaderView(headerLayout);
```